# What to use to remove Magnesium sulfate ( palm tree fertilizer) stain on the driveway

Tags: concrete

need some advice on what to use to remove magnesium sulfate stain from a concrete driveway. I have used ammonia, 30% vinegar but none were effective.

Comment: it should be readily dissolvable in water, maybe another ingredient is causing the stain.

Comment: The magnesium salt (palm tree fertilizer) was spread and the base of the trunks. It rained, then workers walking through that area tracked it onto my driveway resulting is obvious footprints. The instructions tell you that it (magnesium sulfate- which is Epsom Salt) will stain concrete. I would like to remove the stains with a “soft” approach- chemicals in order  to avoid using a mechanical approach- grinding disc etc

Answer (score 2):

The best concrete cleaner I have found for stubborn stains is diluted muriatic acid. You can purchase it in diluted form at most hardware stores. I recently used it to remove dried tung oil from a concrete patio.
You need to be sure to wear gloves and protective goggles if applying it by hand. Follow directions on the bottle. In my case I left it on overnight covered with a plastic tarp. In your case you may not need to leave it on overnight. Be aware that you need to protect surrounding vegetation when applying it and rinsing it off.

Comment: Fully agree and definitely dilute, if muriatic acid won’t work not much else will. Don’t go two strong those bubbles that form are the real scrubbing bubbles eating the surface of the concrete best cleaner there is.

Comment: Muriatic ( aka hydrochloric  ) will dissolve concrete  ,  I would not leave it unattended. It won't stop until the acid is gone/neutralized .